# How can I pass data into textformfield in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
    class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color? color;
  final IconData? icon;
  final Widget? child;
  const CardWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    this.color,
    this.icon,
    this.child,
  });

  @override
  State<CardWidget> createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

final controllers = List.generate(12, (index) => TextEditingController());

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          color: widget.color,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Icon(
                widget.icon,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 32,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
              
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 30,
                ),
                child: TextFormField(
                 
                  controller: controllers[],

                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => AddCard())));
                  },
                ),
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CardWidget I use to show on homepage

```
    class AddCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        ),
        itemCount: 12,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemTile(
          cardNo: index,
          callback: (p0) {
            controllers[index].text = p0.toString();
          })),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The page where I redirect the user when clicking on the TextFormField.

```
   class ItemTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int cardNo;

  const ItemTile(
    this.cardNo,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ListTile(
        onTap: () { 
        },
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Tuş ${cardNo + 1}',
            key: Key('text_$cardNo'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have cards 1 to 12 and each card has numbers 1 to 12 inside. I want to pass these texts to `TextFormField` when the user clicks on the card.

There are 12 Card designs on my homepage. There is a textFormField inside each of these cards. When the TextFormField is clicked, it goes to a list that I created with GridView in AddCard. There are 12 elements in this list. There are numbers from 1 to 12 inside these 12 elements. When I click on one of them, I want the number there to be assigned to the one I clicked, in the 12 textFormField on the homepage.

Comment: Are you using a different page/route to pass data ?

Answer (score 0):

On ListTile ontap use navigator pop and pass data on second position.

```dart
  onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, "cardNo");
        },
```

And on main file

```dart
child: TextFormField(
   controller: controllers[1], /// your TextFiled index
    onTap: () async{
    final data  = await Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => AddCard())));
  controllers[1].text  = "$data";
 },
    ),
```

---

You can use a callback method, I passing data for future case, or could just use VoidCallback

```dart
class ItemTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int cardNo;
  final Function(int) callback;

  const ItemTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.cardNo,
    required this.callback,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color color = Colors.primaries[cardNo % Colors.primaries.length];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: color.withOpacity(0.3),
        onTap: () {
          callback(cardNo);
        },
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Tuş ${cardNo + 1}',
            key: Key('text_$cardNo'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can get the value like

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemTile(
    cardNo: index,
    callback: (p0) {
      _controller.text = p0.toString();
    }),
```

Comment: Since I have 12 cards and they are controlled by a single controller, when I click on a value from 1 to 12, all TextFormFields show the same value.

Comment: for 12cards, you need to use 12 controllers , you can create a list of controller

Comment: List<TextEditingController> myController = []; 

This is how I defined it. But how do I write it across the controller? I'm getting an error. 
I also defined Controller for TextFormField controller: myController[], like this

Comment: is it fixed by length and used on GridView `AddCard`?

Comment: try to create a list on AddCard llike `final controllers = List.generate(12, (index) => TextEditingController());` and will be used like  `callback: (p0) { controllers[index].text = p0.toString();`

Comment: So how should I define the controller in the textFormField?

Comment: seems like I misunderstood  something, is `AddCard` having all 12 textFiled if not can you update the question

Comment: There are 12 Card designs on my homepage. There is a textFormField inside each of these cards. When the TextFormField is clicked, it goes to a list that I created with GridView in AddCard. There are 12 elements in this list. There are numbers from 1 to 12 inside these 12 elements. When I click on one of them, I want the number there to be assigned to the one I clicked, in the 12 textFormField on the homepage.

Comment: I also added a photo to the question. To explain my question more clearly.

Comment: you have another gridview for top ?

Comment: No there is only one gridView

Comment: Can you from full sample code from scaffold including Card >> TextFiled

Comment: Ok why you are using navigator ?  do you like to navigate on different page ?

Comment: I added 2 images to the beginning of the question. The first is my homepage. When I press the textFormFields here, I direct it to the place in the 2nd Photo. From here, when the user presses a card, I want to write the text in that card into the textFormField in the first image.

Comment: Ok you like pass data between two pages ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to pass data between two screens.

Comment: once the user tap on ListTile do you like to pop back and set the index  ?

Comment: Yes. For example, the user clicked on the textFormField in the first card on the homepage and went to Page 2. Here, too, he clicked on the card named "Tuş 3". After clicking this I want the user to go back to the homepage and write "Tuş 3" in the first textFormField they click.

Answer (score 0):

set the `TextEditingController` to the global scope, and don't make it private with `_`

```
final myController = TextEditingController();
```

then use it in your `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
          controller: myController,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => AddCard())));
          },
        ),
```

now in the `onTap` of `ListTile`, assign a value to the `TextFormField`:

```
onTap: () { 
 myController.text = "your text value";     
 },
```